# What kind of implication does `any` have on concrete generic protocol types?

Tags: swift, generics, existential-type, associated-types

I want to understand the implications of `any` when using specialized generic protocols in Swift. Here is my code:

```
protocol ShapeA {
}

protocol ShapeB {
    associatedtype AAA
}

protocol BaseC<T> {
    associatedtype T
}

protocol ShapeC: BaseC<Int> {
}

protocol Maker {
    func makeShapeA() -> ShapeA
    func makeShapeB() -> any ShapeB
    func makeShapeC() -> any ShapeC
}
```

- Why does `makeShapeC` requires `any` before return type? From my perspective `ShapeC` is a protocol that is fully specified, just like `ShapeA`. What exactly is the difference?
- Why doesn't `makeShapeA` require `any`? It's existential type just according to the descriptions that I find online...
- In case I leave the code as it is: is there an actual performance difference between `makeShapeA` and `makeShapeC` as they both return existential types as far as I can tell?

Comment: "Why doesn't makeShapeA require `any`?" Don't worry, it will eventually. The problem is that you are looking at a half-finished piece of work.